# how to improve error message for WebDriver ExpectedCondition?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I have a utility method like this:

```
public void verifyTitle(int secsToWait) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, secsToWait)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
}
```

When it fails, the message is:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
>
> Timed out after 2 seconds waiting for title to be: Some title here
>   Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11
>   21:42:35' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version:
>   '3.0.0-16-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_04' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown

I can't find the API for giving a better error message. What I would like to have is:

> Timed out after 2 seconds waiting for title to be: Some title here
>   (but the title was: Some other title)

I can do it with try/catch like presented below but maybe there is some other option?

```
public void verifyTitle(int secsToWait) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, secsToWait)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(String.format("Expected page title [%s] but was [%s]", title, driver.getTitle()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the issue with catching the exception is. You are catching it and rethrowing it with better information, this is what you generally do with rethrowing exceptions.

Comment: there is no issue - I am asking if there is some cleaner way without try/catch (ok, I could also use catch-exception library)

Comment: Personally, no, I don't see any better solution, sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `withMessage()` method:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.withMessage("Any message you want");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare with JUnit's **assertEquals** which would provide a better message

Such as:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[something]> but was:<[differentthing]>
```

Answer (score -1):

cal this when u want to pass a scenario.

Public CustomWebDriverException(String msg, WebDriver custWebDriver) {

```
    super(msg);

    this.driver = custWebDriver;
```

}

call this constructor when there is a catch

public CustomWebDriverException(Throwable e, WebDriver selenium) {

```
    super(e.getMessage());
    this.driver = selenium;
}
```

let me know more about your setup and other thing.. like framework, because there are few thing whch you can manage with testNg or maven